# Unable to Boot into other Hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, uefi, mbr, dualboot

I have 2 drives in my windows laptop, one is HDD and another one is SSD.

Initially I installed Windows on the main Hard disk and after few months I bought an SSD (lets call this SSD1) and installed another Windows 10 OS. The boot records are on the Hard drive and now I bought another SSD and want to replace the old Hard drive with the new SSD drive (lets call this SSD2). Is there any way I can boot into SSD1 and replace the old HDD with the SSD2 as a backup drive?

PS: Apologies in advance for the confusion if any.

Comment: Do this in 2 steps: at first forget about the new SSD and make the old SSD bootable without HDD. Then the second step will be easy.

Comment: Also make sure you only have one drive connected when trying to boot, initially. This prevents confusion with the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

1. rearrange your boot order in BIOS https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-change-your-computers-boot-order
2. install a disk cloner (you could use any software you want, but i'll recommend AOMEI Backupper since it's free and it also can copy your boot records)